# what should I do if the project name contains hyphen in rust

Tags: rust

I am a newbie of rust, when I tried to write a rust web api, but the project contains hyphen so I could not use it, if the project name like `diesel_demo` , I could use it like this:

```
use diesel_demo::schema::posts::dsl::*;
```

but if my project name like `diesel-demo`, what should I do to use it? I can not change my project name now with hyphen `reddwarf-music`. I read the docs and tell me the cargo will trans the `-` to `_` by default, so I am use it like this:

```
use reddwarf_music::schema::posts::dsl::*;
```

but shows error like this:

```
~/Documents/GitHub/reddwarf-music on  develop! ⌚ 17:56:51
$ cargo build                                                                                                                                  ‹ruby-2.7.2›
   Compiling hello-rocket v0.1.0 (/Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/reddwarf-music)
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `reddwarf_music`
 --> src/biz/music/music.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use reddwarf_music::schema::posts::dsl::*;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `reddwarf_music`
```

what should I do handle the `-` in rust? By the way the `scheme` is generate in my local src, not from third package. This is my project structure:

[image]

this is my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "reddwarf_music"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.1", features = ["json"] }
rand = "0.8.4"
serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.64"
reqwest = "0.11.4"

# database
diesel = { version = "1.4.4", features = ["postgres"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
```

Comment: have you try `use crate::schema` ?

Comment: [rename dependency?](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html?highlight=rename,depende#renaming-dependencies-in-cargotoml) ( I am assuming you are using reddwarf music as a dependency because of the error ? `Compiling hello-rocket`)

Comment: no, the reddwarf music not a dependencies. @ÖmerErden it is my project name, my project named `reddwarf-music`.

Comment: Well then I assume your package name in cargo.toml doesn't match with your project's folder name

Comment: `name = "hello-rocket"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a crate you don't use the crates name with `use`, rather, you refer to the crate itself using the identifier `crate`.

So *inside* your crate "reddwarf-music", when you want to `use` an internal symbol, instead of writing

```
use reddwarf_music::schema::posts::dsl::*;
```

you write

```
use crate::schema::posts::dsl::*;
```